# The name **** Does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, wpf

The name Browser, TosBrowser and MainTabControl throw errors. Apparently they do not exist in current context. I double checked the MainWindow.xaml and the names are correct. Can't figure out the next step to troubleshoot/fix the issue. Pretty sure I forgot to call something.

I am fairly new to WPF and c# over all, so any help would be wonderful.
MainWindow.xaml.cs is below

```
 public void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Browser.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            TosBrowser.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            DataContext = this;
            #region ToS

            if (!Config.Instance.TosAccepted)
            {
                RightWindowCommands.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            else
            {
                MainTabControl.SelectedIndex = 1;
            }

            #endregion
        }
```

here is a snipit of the MainWindow.xaml

```
<TabControl Margin="3,-36,3,3" x:Name="MainTabControl" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" >
        <TabItem x:Name="TosTabItem" Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Visible">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="9*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="82*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <WebBrowser x:Name="TosBrowser" Visibility="Visible" Margin="10,10,10,32" Source="http://api.glariful.com/public/tos" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
            <Button Content="{DynamicResource AcceptTosButton}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,90,2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" Click="TosAccept_Click" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <Button Content="{DynamicResource DeclineTosButton}" Margin="0,0,10,2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="75" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Click="TosDecline_Click" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
</TabItem>
        <TabItem x:Name="NewsTabItem" Header="News" Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                <WebBrowser x:Name="Browser" Visibility="Visible" Source="http://api.glariful.com/public/news/html" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem x:Name="SettingsTabItem" Header="Settings" Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">

            </Grid>
        </TabItem>




    </TabControl>
```

Comment: Can you show me the xaml file?

Comment: Is this code in the code-behind file for the view (like `MainWindow.xaml.cs`)?

Comment: Yes, This is MainWindows.xaml.cs

Comment: No, I mean _without_ .cs, only `MainWindow.xaml`

Comment: @Sweeper , Edited to main post.

Comment: Try changing x:Name to just Name.

Comment: Ok I see, I'll look into it.

Comment: @Shar1er80 , Tried that. No go...

Comment: Have you renamed your class, but not in the `x:Class` attribute of the xaml file?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: @Sweeper Could it be VS2015?  (doubt it)

Comment: I used VS2015 and it worked just fine. I created a few WPF apps in VS2013 Pro and it still works.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569782/how-to-access-control-in-code-behind-that-was-created-in-xaml or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12231743/why-is-my-control-not-accessible-in-codebehind should help.